# Correct regex format for taking two values from textfile separated by pipe-delimiter - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to retrieve values from a local textfile named "text.txt". After retrieval, PHP would then create a multidimensional array containing said values. The values inside the textfile are separated by a pipe-delimiter and I aim to

This is the content of the textfile - "text.txt".

```
ExampleOne|23
Ryan|24
Sample Name|25.6
Dogg|31.5
```

This is the PHP code I've written:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
$data = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $line = trim(fgets($file));
   if (preg_match('/--I don't know the format--/', $line, $matches)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'Name' => $matches[0]),
            'BMI' => $matches[1],
        );
   }
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

And this is the output I'm trying to achieve.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ExampleOne
            [BMI] => 23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ryan
            [BMI] => 24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Sample Name
            [BMI] => 25.6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Dogg
            [BMI] => 31.5
        )
)
```

My issue comes with incorrect regex format. I can't seem to create the proper format to do what I aim for.

I'm open for suggestions. I'm not sure if preg_match() is the ideal way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, but from what I've seen so far, it might be so. Its just a matter of figuring the proper regex format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easier by using PHP’s explode function.

```
foreach (explode('|', $fileData) as $line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to read the whole file, and use a pattern with 2 named capture groups `Name` and `BMI`. In the resulting multidimensional array, you can remove all numerical keys.

You can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` from PHP 5.6

The pattern

```
^(?<Name>[^|\r\n]+)\|(?<BMI>[^|\r\n]+)$
```

It matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<Name>[^|\r\n]+)` Capture group `Name` match 1+ times any char except `|` or a newline
- `\|` Match a pipe char `|`
- `(?<BMI>[^|\r\n]+)` Capture group `BMI` match 1+ times any char except `|` or a newline
- `$` End of string

For example

```
$data = file_get_contents("text.txt");
preg_match_all("/^(?<Name>[^|\r\n]+)\|(?<BMI>[^|\r\n]+)$/m", $data, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$result = array_map(function($arr){
    return array_filter($arr, function($k){
        return !is_numeric($k);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}, $matches);
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ExampleOne
            [BMI] => 23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ryan
            [BMI] => 24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Sample Name
            [BMI] => 25.6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Dogg
            [BMI] => 31.5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work.

```
   if (preg_match('/(.*?)\|(.*)/', $line, $matches)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'Name' => $matches[1],
            'BMI' => $matches[2]
        );
   }
```